# Equation of a 2D 'helix'

Tags: geometry

I need to write some code to draw a 2D helix. Not a spiral, but more like the 2D projection of a normal helix. This would be like the representation of the gluon particle in a Feynman Diagram. This is shown in the image.

[image]

What would the equation of this shape look like?

Comment: Use a circle with a time dependent center.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProlateCycloid.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can indeed use the projection of a 3D helix.

The parametric equations of an horizontal helix can be written

$$\begin{cases}x=r\cos t,\\y=r\sin t,\\z=at.\end{cases}$$

Then rotating by an horizontal angle $\theta$ and dropping the $z$ coordinate,

$$\begin{cases}x'=r\cos t\cos\theta-at\sin\theta,\\y'=r\sin t\end{cases}.$$

These are cycloids.

[image]

Comment: They are not pure, but scaled (prolate) cycloids... projections of a helix in $(x−y) $ plane rotated about $y $ axis through angle $θ$.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Feynman]

As a start,

$$ (x,y)= ( a t - k \sin t , a - k\, \cos t) ,(0<t< 10 \pi) $$

```
a = 1 ; k = 1.8;
ParametricPlot[{ a t - k Sin[t]  , a - k  Cos[t] + .08 t},  { t, 
   0, 10 Pi} , AspectRatio -> Automatic, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

in *Mathematica* code. If you don't want the ramp up, remove the last $.08 t$. Can vary $k/a$ ratio to influence the curling, and also the $t$ limits to lengthen the helix or shorten it...